# How to update item relationships with eve-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

I've created a simple `eve-sqlalchemy` application that has a `User` and `Role` resource in order to mimic [an example on their webpage](https://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html). The `User` class can have multiple roles. The full example code is provided below.

I'm interested in being able to `POST` users with roles, or `PATCH` a user's roles. I haven't been able to find a way to do this without running into errors.

It appears that `eve-sqlalchemy` enforces the type of `User.roles` to integer, which is the `Role` class's primary key `id`. If I instead set the `POST` or `PATCH` request to have the `roles` field be an integer, `eve-sqlalchemy` complains that the `userroles` association table doesn't exist in `self.driver.app.config['SOURCES']`. While I could make these changes (i.e. make the `userroles` table a declarative ORM and register it with the decorator) I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about it.

In summary, how does `eve-sqlalchemy` expect me to `POST` a `User` with a list of `roles`, or `PATCH` a user's existing roles?

### The server:

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.utils import config

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, func, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

from eve_sqlalchemy.decorators import registerSchema
from eve_sqlalchemy import SQL
from eve_sqlalchemy.validation import ValidatorSQL


ID_FIELD = 'id'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////tmp/eve-sqla-test.db'


config.ID_FIELD = ID_FIELD
config.ITEM_LOOKUP_FIELD = ID_FIELD


Base = declarative_base()


userroles_table = Table('userroles', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey("roles.id"), primary_key=True)
)


class CommonColumns(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    _created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    _updated = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    _etag = Column(String(40))


class Role(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    role = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)


class User(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    login = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    roles = relationship("Role", backref="users", secondary=userroles_table)


def create_entries():
    '''Creates test entries for querying with eve'''
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.create_all()

    SessionMaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    s = SessionMaker()

    u1 = User(login='user1')
    u1.roles.append(Role(role='admin'))

    u2 = User(login='user2')
    u2.roles.append(Role(role='user'))

    s.add_all((u1, u2))
    s.commit()


def run():
    '''Runs the eve server'''

    for table in (User, Role):
        registerSchema(table.__tablename__)(table)

    users = User._eve_schema[User.__tablename__]
    users.update({
        'item_methods': ['GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
        'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
    })

    roles = Role._eve_schema[Role.__tablename__]
    roles.update({
        'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
    })

    DOMAIN = {
        'users': users,
        'roles': roles,
    }

    SETTINGS = {
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
        'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False,
        'ID_FIELD': ID_FIELD,
        'ITEM_LOOKUP_FIELD': ID_FIELD,
        'DOMAIN': DOMAIN,
    }

    app = Eve(validator=ValidatorSQL, data=SQL, settings=SETTINGS)

    db = app.data.driver
    Base.metadata.bind = db.engine
    db.Model = Base

    app.run(debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''Test area'''

    #create_entries()
    run()
```

### The requests:

```
import json

import requests


u4 = {
   'login': 'user4',
}


# users get works
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/users')
print(r.text)


# user creation works
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/users', json=u4)
print(r.text)


# roles get works
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/roles')
print(r.text)


# user creation with roles fail
u5 = {
   'login': 'user5',
   'roles': [1,]
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/users', json=u5)
print(r.text)  # {"_issues": {"roles": ["field 'roles' could not be coerced", "must be of integer type"]}, "_status": "ERR"}


# user patch with role fails
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/users/1')
patch_headers = {"If-Match": r.json()['_etag'], 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

r = requests.patch('http://localhost:5000/users/1', headers=patch_headers, json={'roles': [1,]})
print(r.text)  # {"_issues": {"roles": ["field 'roles' could not be coerced", "must be of integer type"]}, "_status": "ERR"}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was:

1. Convert `userroles_table` from a table to a declarative class `UserRole`.
2. Register `UserRole` with `eve_sqlalchemy`
3. Add `UserRole` to `DOMAIN`.

The association table could then be queried or modified directly through a new resource endpoint `user_roles`. `eve_sqlalchemy` appears to hide the foreign keys when generating schema so it's important to include a relationship to foreign keys.